# Deleteting a temp file after loading into JVM

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, java-native-interface

Is it ok to delete a library file right after we load it using the system.loadLibrary() function...? Here is the scenario...

We are using JNI to use the DomainSocket utility which is written in C language to call from a Java app. We are packing the .SO files in the same jar and using a utility to create a temp file on the file system and load the .SO using the loadLibrary function. We are using the File.createTempFile() which create a unique temp file. We are using the deteleOnExit()to delete the temp file on JVM shutdown.

On a stand alone application on JVM, this works fine. But we have an issue when deployed to web container like Tomcat as we can have multiple applications running on the same JVM. Firstly a temp file is created for each App deployed. The real problem is that when the App is stopped and started or re-deployed, the temp file is not deleted, but a new one created. All the temp files are deleted when the JVM shuts down (Tomcat restarted).

We experimented with a solution to delete the temp file after the loadLibrary(). This seems to works fine. A new temp file is created on restart and deleted right after loading.

Wanted to check if anybody has some pointers/suggestions?

We do not want to use the common/lib mechanism to load the .SO files only once per container as we want to make these .SO files part of the application.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ok to delete a library file right after we load it using the system.loadLibrary() function...?

Nope. The OS is free to "unload" the library at any time and might have to re-load the binary from the disk. If you delete the file (and it's not actually held-open by the process), then you'll get some very weird behavior .. probably something like a "BUS ERROR" or other barely-explainable condition.

Even if the library is not dropped from memory and re-loaded from the disk, various OSs have flags for "lazy loading" and other things that can get you into a race-condition situation where you might delete the on-disk library artifact before all the code was actually loaded from it.

> We are using the File.createTempFile() which create a unique temp file. We are using the deleteOnExit() to delete the temp file on JVM shutdown.

This seems like a reasonable approach, except for the problems you are encountering. Instead of using `File.createTempFile`, why not use a predictable filename in a predictable place (such as `/tmp/libgoodstuff.so`)? If you do that, then you'll only have to create (and schedule the deletion of) a single file (per library you want to load).

> [I] wanted to check if anybody has some pointers/suggestions?

Placing the `.so` file in the application is going to be tough to manage unless you really know your target environments very well. For example, you'll need to make sure you have your target architecture and OS correct, etc.

The bottom line is that native libraries as a part of a distributable application are a pain in the neck with Java and should be avoided unless there are no other options.

Comment: What OS are you refering to when you say it may unload libraries at any time?

Comment: @apangin No specific OS that I had in mind. But there is no POXIX, etc. requirement that the code stays loaded and therefore the disk-based artifact is free to disappear. I would expect "undefined behavior" to be the result of loading, then deleting a shared-library from the disk.

Comment: Well, I don't know OSes (at least among supported by Oracle JDK) that will cause an application to crash when a shared library is deleted. Usually OS will either deny deletion (Windows) or just unlink the filename (Linux) keeping the file data on the disk. Removing the file does not affect the memory mappings of this file already opened.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this approach may work, but with certain restrictions.

When `System.loadLibrary` is called, the corresponding `.so` file is mmap-ed into the process address space. When you remove the file, the corresponding `dentry` is immediately removed, but not the `inode`. That is, the file name is unlinked, but the file data is kept until the last reference to the file is released.

This is the way how package managers install updates. They may delete executable files and shared libraries even if they are used by running processes. OS will ensure that the running programs continue to use old version of libraries, while the new programs will load new versions.

However, this approach is not portable. It works on Linux, but not on other OSes and not on every filesystem (consider Windows or FAT, for example). Therefore, I would not recommend to do so unless you know the particular OS platform being used.

Comment: We hot a snag with just one .SO file in the web container. The .SO file loaded by one webapp cannot be loaded by another webapp because of classloader. Tomact assign a unique classloader to each webapp and multiple loading of the *same* .SO will not work...

Comment: @user2089210 Right, I've missed that part. So, if you don't need the application to be portable across platforms, it's OK to delete libraries as soon as they are loaded. Well, having a JNI library makes the application non-portable anyway.